# How do I handle versioning for a web application

Tags: svn, version-control, workflow

How to achieve a good versioning system, I do use SVN for updating a code and making them to sit on trunk.
My boss always ask a new feature and before one feature is completes he ask for another feature in same module. How Do I manage Branching in this situation ?

**Note** :
I had posted this Question on programmers.stackexchange.com but some one closed is giving a reason Question Should be subjective. So I'm posting here.

Answer (score 3):

A "good versioning system" depends on the developers contributing to it and the versioning system you use. The main trunk (master branch) contains only stable code. If you detect issues or work on new features, you create a branch for them. You also want to keep the other code as close to the trunk as possible -> therefore, update branches often, so new fixes to the trunk get considered! When the code of your branch works, merge changes to the trunk.

Take a look at this: http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/ for a good intro.

Comment: I agree to udo. Branching is cheap. Try to fix integration issues in the (unstable) feature branches and merge back into the trunk when things look good enough (--reintegrate)